# How do I browse files/music after connecting my iPhone5s to Debian via `bluetoothctl`?

Tags: debian, bluetooth, iphone

I want to browse files (including music) on my iPhone5s from my PC, which is running Debian 8.2 "Jessie" with MATE desktop environment.

I ran `sudo apt-get install bluetoothctl`, then after I run `bluetoothctl`, I did this:

```
power on
devices  # To get the iPhone's MAC address
scan on
agent on
discoverable on
pair IPHONE_MAC_ADDRESS_HERE
trust IPHONE_MAC_ADDRESS_HERE
connect IPHONE_MAC_ADDRESS_HERE
```

I can connect Debian and my iPhone just fine, but where do I go from there?

How do I browse my iPhone's files from Debian?

Comment: Some phones block file browsing over bluetooth.  I would think you need some obex packages installed on the PC, probably obexftp, obexfs.  See if you have them with `dpkg -l | grep obex`